# Как реализовать вертикальный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, css, слайдер

Есть контейнер `div` с `overflow-y: hidden` в нем слайдер с 3 вертикальными слайдами, `jQuery` генерирует и вставляет еще несколько слайдов перед этими тремя, то есть сверху и запускает слайдер добавляя класс active родительскому элементу.
Необходимо, чтобы после вставки этих слайдов слайды прокрутились от текущих трех (после вставки они стали последние в наборе) до первых трех в наборе. Для плавности может быть использована CSS анимация или переход (transition).
Как возможно такое реализовать?

```js
let parent = $('.parent');
let column = $('.column');
column_0 = column[0];
column_0.prepend('<img src=img/test.png>');
column_0.prepend('<img src=img/test.png>');
column_0.prepend('<img src=img/test.png>');
column_0.prepend('<img src=img/test.png>');
column_0.prepend('<img src=img/test.png>');
parent.addClass('active');
```

```css
.parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.parent .column{
    /* ??? */
}
.parent.active .column{
    transition: all 5s linear 0s;
    /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Если не хотите изобретать велосипед, то есть swiper.js с довольно обширным API.

Comment: Довольно легко можно реализовать на плагине jquery cycle
https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=400